# geodist with SetFilterFloatRange not giving results in sphinx/php

Tags: php, sphinx

I am trying to fetch autosuggestion w.r.t. SetFilterFloatRange() Geodist  but it's not giving me results.

Below is my code

```
  $cl = new SphinxClient();
  $cl->SetServer('127.0.0.1', 9312);
  $cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
  $cl->SetLimits(0, 10);
  $cl->SetGeoAnchor('latitude', 'longitude', (float)deg2rad(32.799) , (float)deg2rad(-86.8073));
  $cl->SetGroupBy('alias_seq', SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR, 'priority DESC', '@geodist ASC');
$cl->SetFilterFloatRange('@geodist', 0.0, 100000); //This line causing issue

  $partialQueryStr = " @keyword $query*";

  $cnt = 0;
  foreach ($neighbours as $key => $value) {
      if(($cnt + 1) == count($neighbours))
      {
          $partialQueryStr .= " @geohash $value*";
      }
      else
      {
          $partialQueryStr .= " @geohash $value* | ";
      }
      $cnt++;
  }

  $cl->AddQuery($partialQueryStr, 'indexer');
  $result = $cl->RunQueries();
```

Sphinx source code

```
    sql_query = //...simple SELECT query fetch below attributes

    sql_attr_uint = sphinxid
    sql_attr_uint = seq
    sql_attr_uint = alias_seq
    sql_field_string = keyword
    sql_field_string = txt
    sql_field_string = analyzed_object
    sql_attr_uint = priority
    sql_field_string = type
    sql_field_string = geohash
    sql_attr_uint = latitude
    sql_attr_uint = longitude
```

> With SetFilterFloatRange gets 0 results and,
>
> Without SetFilterFloatRange gets results

Comment: I calculate the distance in PHP, because last I checked Sphinx was off by a few miles.  Rather or not this is fixed, I have no idea.  But our clients need the distance to exactly match ( at least what google maps and various other distance calculators say )

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Please check my updates.

Comment: Sorry I don't know about sorting, we presort and de-normalize all our sphinx data and keep the search as simple as possible. But we also do 180k searches per minute ... so.  Sorry I really wish I could help you further.

Comment: If dont inlcude the `SetFilterFloatRange` in the query, what are the values of `@geodist` you get in the results. Are they actully between 0 and 100000 ??

Comment: It gives me simply 0 results

Comment: Thats not what you said above! *Without SetFilterFloatRange gets results*

Comment: Ok let me check